# Can't use @@ServerName in answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown

The Markdown editor is giving an error when using `@@ServerName` in an answer. I tried to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532578/ssrs-displaying-the-datasource-server-name-in-your-report) but kept getting an error. Putting a space between the `@` symbols lets me post the answer but it is syntactically incorrect now. I don't see anything obvious in the [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to indicate why this would be an error.

Here is the error (with Bad Gateway network error):

[image]

Strangely enough, the commenting system let me enter this properly to explain that I couldn't use it in the actual answer.

Comment: Strangely, other people (including me) could edit and remove the space. Very strange indeed. (You can remove the comment on your answer now)

Comment: Yes, very weird - I tried to post it many times, both on SO and here, and just got errors. Not sure what is going on... maybe I should just delete this if it is only happening for me?

Comment: Do you remember what specific error it was? At the very least, was it generated by the browser or the site?

Comment: I used to have a Firefox extension for password management that treated @@ as special input in text fields. Do you happen to have something like that installed?

Comment: No, I'm using Chrome, no add-ins

Comment: @BoltClock It was a site error, not browser. I just tried again and still get the error. I have added a screencap of the generic error message to the question.

Comment: I delete my answer as it isn't really helpful. Instead, I put the link to [my test on MSE using FireFox 31](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238703/241919) just to show that there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Actually, I recall having problems with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23692184/revisions) along the same lines and had to jump through hoops to try to get it to save (hence the "*will this work???*" revision comment)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any failed requests from you in the access logs, nor exceptions in the error log. If this happens again, can you check (via Chrome dev tools or Fiddler or similar) whether there's a request being made to the server, and what the actual response is?

Comment: Blocked by a proxy/firewall perhaps?

Comment: @balpha added Chrome dev tools network error.

Comment: Chances are that that's indeed a broken proxy or something like that. Assuming you're at work, maybe talk to your sysadmins about it? (And if that's not it, please show the full server response).

Comment: While it looks like that, why would the the proxy suddenly work if I put a space between the `@`s or if I post the same text in a comment? It is only when posting in titles and answers that is errors. It is weird...

Comment: I just [checked from home] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/238784#238784) and it worked fine so its definitely something up with our work setup. Strange that it looks like an posting error though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is related to a proxy issue at your workplace. Very strange issue indeed, but cannot be reproduced by anyone else at this time.